# how to hide button for normal users and show for admin

Tags: php, html, hide

I want to hide button in search menu to specific page for normal users so they can't access to page witch is for administrators only. i'm new at writing this code so i'm asking you guys who have much more knowledge than me for help.

I want to hide File/page name **upload.php** for normal users and show for administrators only

Is anyone know how could i do this with php?

---

i'm really appreciate for every help. Thank you!

Comment: you first need to post your code, whatever you have tried.

Comment: Good to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Alorika ye i would but i don't know how to even start i just want a example how to do this and i will try to do it myself than..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give an advice without your context, but an simple example for your scenario:

```
// Normal Page
if($_SESSION['user_level'] > x){
    //show button
}

// Admin-Only-Page
if($_SESSION['user_level'] < x){
    die("Access denied");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can capture `user type` of user's in `session`. And, according to user type show / hide button.

```
<?
if(S_SESSION['userType'] == 'Admin') {
    //Show
}
if(S_SESSION['userType'] == 'User') {
    //Hide
}
?>
```

Comment: so you telling me like this `<?
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$userType = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Rank']);
if(S_SESSION['userType'] == 'Administrator') {
    //Show
}
if(S_SESSION['userType'] == 'User') {
    header("Location: prva.php");
}
?>`

Answer (score 1):

Depends of how you define the administrator,  if he is the user whose the Id is 1 for example, use the following script:

```
<?php
 $current_user_id = // get it from the session if user is logged in
  If ($current_user_id == 1):
?>
<input ...>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to set one flag in Database as user is admin or normal user.
after that in your code check with condition that logged in user is admin or not;

for example admin role is 1 then:

```
if($user->role == 1){
 // your button code
}
```

simple, Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

for example, you can use following Conditional statement :

```
if ($user -> role == 1){
   // `enter code here`
}
```